# Jetpack Compose Core Splashscreen Theme

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, splash-screen, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am using the latest stable version of the Core-SplashScreen api. `androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1`

When I launch the app, it loads the splash screen correctly. Then using "postSplashScreenTheme" I tell it what theme to apply after the Splash Screen is finished.

XML Code:

```
<style name="Theme.AppName" parent="android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar" />

<style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#DFDFDF</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/logo_no_background</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.AppName</item>
</style>
```

MainActivity.kt:

```
setContent {
    AppNameTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
       ) {
            Greeting("Android")
         }
    }
}
```

Theme.kt:

```
@Composable
fun AppNameTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }

        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

| After Splash Screen Clears | After Screen Rotation |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Android app after splash Screen] | [image: Android app after rotation] |

As you can see, the statusBarColor is set to red after the rotation. I believe that is because of this `window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()` in the theme.kt. I would like to be able to set the postSplashScreenTheme to the AppNameTheme. I understand that it is probably not possible. I could just update the `Theme.AppName` to handle the statusBarColor, but I feel like it's not the best solution. Does anyone have ideas on a better solution?

Comment: This is because ```dynamicColor: Boolean = true``` for android 12 and above so if you want only single color theme you can disable it and check if it works as you want.

Comment: @ChiragThummar that did not fix the issue. It did change the color it was tunring to. The issue is when I rotate the device, the "AppNameTheme" is being applied after I rotate. I need the "AppNameTheme" to be the postSplashScreenTheme. I dont think that is possible though because it is not an xml file.